# How to get SMTP-ID in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I need to have an Azure Logic App that trigger on different SMTP-ID (alias) for the Exchange account. Connected to Office 365.

The issue is that the "to" field always contains the primary address, e.g. "user@domain" instead of "alias@domain".

The app will read attachments and create files on SharePoint, e-mails are created from a printer so need to use e-mail address name as the target folder, and not the e-mail subject line.

Any ideas on how to parse out the SMTP ID in Logic App's Office 365 connector? Is it even possible?

Comment: There is a SMTP connector also.

Comment: There are no SMTP connector for receiving e-mails, there are "SMTP - Send Email", and there are Outlook.com connector, which I doubt work with Office 365 Exchange account?

Answer (score 1):

Found a workable solution, and that was using distribution lists. When using distribution lists, the "To" address is the one of the list and not of the e-mail account holder. :-)